# Phaser 3 this.add.graphics works inside create function, but not outside?

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

When I add graphics to a scene with `this.add.graphics` inside of the create function, it works fine, graphics are added. When I try the same code inside of a custom function, say a function called `redrawGame()`, I get an error message saying:

```
Undefined is not an object
```

How can add graphics to a scene outside of the create function?

Comment: can you post the code of the custom function , and how the custom function is called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depening on your code and code structure, you probably will have to pass the scene *( in this case `this`)* to the custom function, since the `this` object in the custom function refers to a different object.

```
 // if you want to call it from the "create" function
 function create(){
     redraw(this);
     ...
 }
 ...
 // Or if you want to call it from the "update" function
 function update(){
     redraw(this);
     ...
 }

 ...

 function redraw(scene){
     scene.add.graphics();
     ...
 }
```

But without seeing your code, I can't say, if this is your issue, or if there is a different problem.

**Update, for custom function call on window *resize-event* :**

To check for the `resize` Event of the browser/window, I would use the phaser events ([link to documentation](https://photonstorm.github.io/phaser3-docs/Phaser.Scale.Events.html#event:RESIZE__anchor)):

```
 // setup in the create function
 this.scale.on('resize', resizeGame, this);
```

the third parameter is the scope of the callback function *(in this case `scene`)*, so your `resizeGame` function would have to call `redraw`, like this:

```
function resizeGame(){
   ...
   redraw(this); // due to the scope passed third parameter of 'this.scale.on'
   ...
}
```

Comment: I have a `window.addEventListener("resize", resizeGame);`. Inside of resizeGame I call `redrawGame()`. I want to resize some rectangles widths on every resize, but it doesn't work

Comment: @summer9844 I update my answer hope this helps